# Mock exception correctly in test

Tags: python, exception, mocking

I have a try catch block and I want to hijack the main function called to return an exception with a message -->

```
  def some_func():  
     try:
        my_function()
    except Exception as e:
        if e.message == 'XYZ':
            # do stuff
            return
        raise
```

I'm trying to test this but my test keeps raising the exception instead:

```
    @mock.patch('import_path_for_my_function')
    def test_some_func(self, mock_my_func):

        mock_my_func.side_effect = mock.Mock(side_effect=Exception('XYZ'))
        some_func()
        # do some assertions
```

but it looks like this raises the Exception instead:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 960, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1026, in _mock_call
    result = effect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 960, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1020, in _mock_call
    raise effect
Exception: XYZ
```

Why is this happening and how should I hijack `my_function` to raise an exception which can be caught by the method calling it.

Comment: Could you please show us how you are invoking some_func(). Also you might consider renaming "mock_exception" to "mock_my_function"

Comment: @bearrito thanks! I just edited my code to show where i'm invoking function i'm testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but doing it in a wrapped way like this worked.

```
    def test_some_func(self):

        with mock.patch('path_to_my_function', side_effect=Exception('XYZ')):
            some_func()
            # do some assertions
```